# How to sort a list of different filenames sorting a number in the filename with bash to find the "newest" filename in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, scripting

I run a command, `getFiles`, that outputs a newline delimited list filenames. Very similar to the output of `ls -1`. The filenames all end in a number representing a kind of timestamp. Larger numbers are more recent. The filenames follow no pattern. e.g. `file1234`, `other44234`, `something34142`, `carrot123`.

I need to find the filename with the largest number (numerically). In this example `other44234`.

After finding the filename I need to pass it as an argument into another command. i.e. `doItToIt "$THE_FILE"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([a-Z]+)([0-9]+)/\1 \2/' files.txt |
    sort -n -k2 |
    tail -n1 |
    tr -d ' '
```

```
other44234
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
$ cat files.txt
file1234
other44234
something34142
carrot123
```

One convoluted chain of commands:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$/\2 \1\2/p' files.txt | sort -nr | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
other44234
```

But once we pull `awk` into the mix there's really no need for anything else, eg:

```
awk '{ if (match($0,/([0-9]+)$/)) {      # if we find a string of numbers at the end of the line (aka filename)
           sfx=substr($0,RSTART)         # strip off the number and ...
           if (sfx>max) {                # if larger than the previous find then ...
              max=sfx                    # make note of the new largest number and ...
              fname=$0                   # grab copy of current line (aka filename)
           }
       }
    }
END { if (fname) print fname}        # if fname is non-blank then print to stdout
' files.txt
```

This also generates:

```
other44234
```

---

Or doing the whole thing in `bash` with a regex and the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array:

```
regex="^.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)$"

fname=""
max=0

while read -r f
do 
    [[ "${f}" =~ $regex ]]                  && 
    [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" -gt "${max}" ]] && 
    max="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"                && 
    fname="${f}"
done < files.txt
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p fname
declare -- fname="other44234"
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxnum=-1
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    n=${fname##*[!0-9]}
    if ((n > maxnum)); then
        maxnum=$n
        maxfile=$fname
    fi
done < <(getFiles)

doItToIt "$maxfile"
```